# MultiTrigger not working When Validation.HasError and IsMouseOver in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, xaml

I have this `TextBox` :

```
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=Cb_AllowDeletingPictures}"
                 Style="{DynamicResource TextBoxInError}">
     <TextBox.Text>
          <Binding Path="TimeBeforeDeletingPicture" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <helpers:TimeBeforeDeletingRule/>
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
          </Binding>
     </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

The `TextBoxInError` Style contains a Template for the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` property and a `MultiTrigger` that sets a tooltip and turns the `BorderBrush` and the `Foreground` to red, this is how it looks like :

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Text="!" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"></TextBlock>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True"></Condition>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now, as you can see in the next screenshot, the ErrorTemplate works just fine showing a red exclamation mark before the TextBox, the problem is that :

- When the Mouse `is not over` the TextBox, neither the Foreground nor the the BorderBrush are red, which is just ok.
- Now when the Mouse `is over` the area of the TextBox, only the Foreground turns red, while the BorderBrush keeps its original behavior when the Mouse is over it.

**When the Mouse is not over the TextBox area :**

[image: When not MouseOver]

**When the Mouse is over the TextBox area :**

[image: When isMouseOver]

Why there is such a behavior, why is it working fot the Foreground and not for the BorderBrush ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *default template of TextBox, trigger is defined which on MouseOver set the BorderBrush to some blue color which you see on mouse over*. That's why your trigger not working. You have to ***override default template and remove that trigger to make it work***.

Declare template in style like this *(I have removed the default trigger from the control template)*:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxInError" TargetType="TextBox">
    <!-- Your other setters -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBoxBase">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    Name="border"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Focusable="False" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled"
                             Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Opacity"
                                TargetName="border" 
                                Value="0.56"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused"
                             Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush"
                                TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush>#FF569DE5</SolidColorBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <!-- Your triggers -->
</Style>
```

Trigger which I have removed from the default template look like this:

```
<Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter
        Property="Border.BorderBrush"
        TargetName="border">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FF7EB4EA</SolidColorBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: Thx @Rohit I think I found what was my problem